# iOS push notification - trying to store deviceID in database using java servlet

Tags: ios, database, push-notification, push, servlet-3.0

I am able to get Device Token, now i am trying to store this token id in DB2 table, using a java servlet, this servlet takes the device id and stores it into database. It is storing some sample device token if i try from my browser. but from iOS code given below it gives reaponse code of 200 but it doesn't store device token to DB and also i don't get any response data as well. Below is the code -

Device id is added in the URL in this below code -

var nsURL = NSURL(string: Constants.StoreDeviceIDURL)

```
            var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: nsURL!)
            //request.addValue(manager.authSessionCookieKeyVal, forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
            var response: NSURLResponse;
            var error : NSError;

            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL!) {(data, response, error) in

                if let httpRes = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                    println("status code=",httpRes.statusCode)
                    if httpRes.statusCode == 200 {
                        println("Data %@",NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
                        // parse data
                    }
                } else {
                    println("error \(error)") // print the error!
                }

            }

            task.resume()
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try This
var url : NSURL = NSURL(string: "yoururl/token=yourtoken")
var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

let task : NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

if let httpRes = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                println("status code=",httpRes.statusCode)
                if httpRes.statusCode == 200 {
                    println("Data %@",NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
                    // parse data
                }
            } else {
                println("error \(error)") // print the error!
            }

});
```

Comment: Thanks Johny, i tried this above code but still same issue, response code is 200 but so response data and device token is not getting stored as well. N also my link is something like this - http://domain:8080/vdws/PushNotification?DeviceID=DeviceToken

Comment: have you debug your code on server wether you are getting data on server or not.

Comment: Yes server code is working fine, i have tested it and also if i try this link through browser it works fine and stores the device id, but not working through iOS

Comment: maybe url which you are creating in app after adding token is not correct.and which you are inserting in browser that was correct

Comment: try to match both of these

Comment: Any idea what could be the issue.. its very urgent pls help

Comment: No its same .. i printed the URL in logcat n tried from browser and it worked

Comment: Yes i have, and there also same issue request to URL is successful but no response data and doesn't store the device id

Comment: try to add contenttype in request.

Comment: I checked the logs in server code, it seems like deviceID receive is null from iOS call but in my URL device id is added. I have printed the url before making this request and url does contain device id in query string. why is my java code getting null for this query string? whereas as i said earlier with Same URL device id is saved successfully from browser.

Comment: try to add request.setValue("text/plain; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

Comment: above line gives error - cannot invoke 'setValue' with with as aurgument list of type (String,forHTTPHeaderField:String)

Comment: make your request object of mutable type NSMutableURLRequest

Comment: Done, still device id received at server is null, n same issue :(

Comment: Ok i am soon sorry it was all my mistake i was printing the right url and i was passing wrong one . So sorry to waste ur time as well and thank u.